# How is $\sum_{r=0}^n C(n-1,r-1)$ possible

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

$\sum_{r=0}^n C(n-1,r-1)$ = C(n-1,-1) + C(n-1,0) + C(n-1,1)+....+ C(n-1,n-1)

How is the 1st term valid i.e C(n-1,-1). If the 1st term is invalid, then $\sum_{r=0}^n C(n-1,r-1)$ is also invalid. Isn't it? Please explain.

But I know if I take C(n,r) = C(n-1,r) + C(n-1,r-1)

S0, C(n-1,r-1) = C(n,r) - C(n-1,r)

Hence $\sum_{r=0}^n C(n-1,r-1)$ = $\sum_{r=0}^n C(n,r)$ - $\sum_{r=0}^n C(n-1,r)$, which equals to $2^{n-1}$. How is this possible?

Comment: How do you define $C(n,r)$? In some cases it can be defined in a way that makes $C(n,-1)=0$, so there is no problem.

Comment: See [Negative Binomial Coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351695/negative-binomial-coefficients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$C(A, B)=\frac{A!}{B!(A-B)!}$$

What is often unconsciously over-applied is the recursive factorial definition $$(k-1)!=\frac{k!}{k}$$
Indeed, this is true wherever $k\in \Bbb N$, and the formula you state $$C(n,r)=C(n-1,r)+C(n-1,r-1)$$
flagrantly uses this very definition. However, when we apply it to $k=0$, we arrive at the massive problem that $(-1)!=\frac 10$. The formula still works under that condition, indeed, if we set $r=0$, we have:
$$\frac{n!}{0!n!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{0!(n-1)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(-1)!n!}\implies\frac{1}{(-1)!n!}=0$$ but clearly the use of an undefined number makes this impossible to use  in our sum.

Comment: Thanks. Is $\sum_{r=0}^n rC(n,r)$ = n$2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Well: $$\sum _{r=0}^n rC(n,r)=n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}C(n-1,r)$$

Comment: rC(n.r) = nC(n-1,r-1). Seems you removed the 1st term nC(n-1,-1) from the summation. Can we simply do that.?

Comment: You've probably seen this as $$\sum_{r=0}^n rC(n,r)=n\sum_{r=1}^n C(n-1,r-1)$$ I shifted the base by $1$.

Answer (score 2):

For integral (even complex) $n$ and integral $r$ the following definition holds:

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-r+1)}{r!}&\quad r\geq 0\\
0&\quad r<0\tag{1}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

See for instance formula (5.1) in chapter *Binomial Coefficients* of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by D.E. Knuth, R.L. Graham and O. Patashnik.

From (1) we conclude $\binom{n-1}{-1}=0$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}}&=\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{r}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{n-1}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we start with index $r=1$, since $\binom{n-1}{-1}=0$ according to (1).
- In (3) we shift the index $r$ by one to start with $r=0$.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.